# Text Widget in a Column affecting Alignment of other widgets in the Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a row of widgets with a small text below them mentioning what that button is for. One of the label is supposed to be multi lined but this is affecting the button in the column. How can I align them properly without it affecting the buttons placed?

[image]

My Widget Structure is something like this:

`Column -> Row -> Column -> GestureDetector, Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` at the `Row` containing all the widgets.

If that doesn't work, post all of the widget parent's code